Can Flux be used to visualize music like the Deep Music Visualizer?
(Sorry if that’s a silly question. I don’t have prior knowledge on this subject.)
I came across the Deep Music Visualizer project on GitHub, which uses BigGAN to visualize music. The project maps music characteristics like pitch and volume to ImageNet class indices and noise vectors, respectively, to generate dynamic and varied visualizations.
I'm wondering if it's possible to achieve similar results using Flux (Stable Diffusion 3). Has anyone attempted to use Flux for music visualization?
Additionally, I found a Python library called LucidDream that uses StyleGAN to generate music visualizations. Could Flux be used in a similar way?
Example Use Case:
Suppose I have an audio file (e.g., an MP3) and I want to generate a video that visualizes the music using Flux. How would I approach this problem? Are there any existing implementations or tutorials that I can follow?
References:

Deep Music Visualizer: https://github.com/msieg/deep-music-visualizer
LucidSonicDream: https://github.com/mikael-alafriz-deel/lucid-sonic-dreams

Please let me know if this is feasible with Flux and if there are any resources available to help me get started.
